# Php image basename

Tags: php, image, filenames

I'm new to php. I found a piece of code that gets all images from a folder. This part works. But now I'd like to echo the filename without extension underneath the image, in the same . I read something about basenames and paths, but I don't get it right...

This works:

```
<?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
$num = $files[$i];
echo '<div class="imgholder"><img src="'.$num.'" class="loadedimg"></div>';
}
?>
```

What I tried (but didn't work):

```
<?php
$path = glob("images/*.*");
$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
$num = $files[$i];
echo '<div class="imgholder"><img src="'.$num.'" class="loadedimg">';

echo basename($path,".jpg");
echo"</div>";
}
?>
```

I get this error on the webpage :  basename() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in .../imgloader.php

Comment: as it says $path is an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, you're trying to use an array as the first parameter for `basename()`.

You probably want this instead:

```
echo basename($num, '.jpg");
```

I'd suggest using more descriptive variable names in your code:

```
$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $img = $files[$i];
    echo '<div class="imgholder"><img src="'.$img.'" class="loadedimg">';
    echo basename($img,".jpg");
    echo"</div>";
}
```

However, I think it's better to use a `foreach` loop instead. You can get rid of the `count()` assignments, and there's no need to declare temporary variables:

```
foreach (glob("images/*.*") as $img) {
    echo '<div class="imgholder"><img src="'.$img.'" class="loadedimg">';
    echo basename($img,".jpg");
    echo"</div>";
}
```

The second parameter in `basename()` is optional, and is only necessary if you want to get the trailing components for images with `.jpg` extension.

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop...

```
foreach ($path as $p)
    {
    echo basename($p, ".jpg");
    }
```

What you have defined as $path is an array of paths, maybe change its name for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have to show the current element. Try:

```
basename($files[$i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

basename() still has the extension if different from the one passed.

```
foreach(glob("images/*.*") as $file) {
    echo '<div class="imgholder"><img src="'.pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME).'" class="loadedimg"></div>';
}
```

Also, if you only want jpg then glob() on *.jpg.